# Почему компилятор даёт предупреждение?

Tags: java, массивы, строки, swing, компилятор

Я использую `JComboBox` в своей программе. У меня есть две строчки кода:

```
String[] items = {"public", "package private"};
JComboBox modificator = new JComboBox(items);
```

Но на одну из этих строк компилятор выдаёт предупреждение:

```
Note: .\helper\Asker.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

С чем это связано? Я вроде как не произвожу никаких "непроверенных или опасных операций". Но я точно уверен, что предупреждение именно об этих двух строчках.

Когда я создаю массив строк другим способом:

```
String [] items = new String[]{"public", "package private"}
```

то ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации, класс[`JComboBox<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) является *обобщённым (generic)*, а значит, вам следует указать тип объектов, которые используются в нём:

```java
JComboBox<String> modificator = new JComboBox<>(items);
```